# Firebase Security Rules: is `if false` optional?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I have a collection for which I need to set up some rules for `create`, `update`. But I want to refuse any `delete`. Must I write `allow delete: if false;` or can I not specify any `delete` rule?

More generally (it's the same question but with a more global scope), if I don't specify any rule nor any `match` for a collection that doesn't exist for now in the database, will it impede hackers that have retro-engineered my APK to execute their requests, for example a `create` access that would create this not-wanted collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security Rules are always **deny by default**.  So if you don't specify a `match` block with an `allow` rule for an operation that's the same as specifying it `if false`.